# Add GET-parameters in URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get

when I reload a page like mysite.com, I want to add the parameter after the URL to get mysite.com/?value=key

This is not an element, but just a reload page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just want to add the parameter `?value=key` to your url - `mysite.com`? I've created a snippet below with a dynamic variable to be the value you want it to be.

```js
/*var key = '123';
var parameter = '?value=' + key;
if ((window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) === -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf('?') === -1)) {
  window.location.href += parameter;
}
*/

if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
  key = '123';
  parameter = '?value=' + key;
  window.location.href += parameter; //sets up the first '?' param
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) === -1) {
  //if param doesnt already exist then add it, won't add again
  key = '1234';
  parameter = '&value=' + key;
  window.location.href += parameter;
}
//change the vars to be the next param
key = '123';
parameter = '&value=' + key;
```

Comment: Thanks. In console i see. And how to see a new variable in the address bar of the browser http://prntscr.com/pcfsjt

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov see my edit for the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but there is an endless page refresh. Can I somehow limit the transmission of the parameter 1 time to reload the page?

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov I have made another edit that checks your URL and if the GET param does not exist then change the URL. It shouldn't fire again once it has been appended.

Comment: Thanks. And if the link already has other parameters, for example: mysite.com/?param=1&filter=3 can I pass my parameter to the end of the link?

mysite.com/?param=1&filter=3&value=123

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov I've added another check to see if the parameter itself exists and if not, it should append at the end even if other ones exist.

Comment: Thanks so much! Last question ;) if the link already has another parameter, then how to check for the validity of two characters '?' ? After all, adding at the end of the GET parameter c '?' will result in an error. There must be '&'

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov could you give me an example of what you mean please? Show the url you'd like and why won't it work?

Comment: 1. when the link already has other GET parameters, and then there can be only one question mark in the link. It turns out mysite.com/?question1=answer1&value=key

In this case, it cannot be mysite.com/?question1=answer1?value=key (two characters '?'), but only one. Therefore, there must be an ampersand sign between requests &

2. when the link has no other parameters, but only the URL itself

In this case, you should get mysite.com/?value=key

Result i want:
1. mysite.com/?question1=answer1&question2=answer2&question3=answer3&value=key
2. mysite.com/?value=key

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov see updated answer yet again. Adds first '?' param and then adds the other '&' values to the URL. Will check again tomorrow if no good

Answer (score 0):

Actually code:

```
var key = '123';
var param1 = '?value=' + key;
var param2 = '&value=' + key;
var flag = 0;

if (!window.location.search) {
    history.pushState(null, null, param1);
    flag++;
}
if (window.location.search && !flag) {
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search + param2);
}
```